# confirm password missing on Appfuse with Spring MVC + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: appfuse

All the online demos for Appfuse on appfuse.org, apart from the Spring MVC + Spring + Hibernate version, have a Confirm Password form element on the signup page.

Is there a reason for the Spring MVC + Spring + Hibernate version not having a Confirm Password form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we removed it as part of the password recovery feature. Feel free to add it back into your project if you like. The model objects should be the same, so the confirmPassword field should already be there.

Comment: Does that imply the confirm password behavior is not considered as necessary when you have the password recovery feature? What I mean is was it a conscious decision to drop confirm password when you added the password recovery feature or just coincidental?

Comment: To clarify I am checking if there was a rational reason for dropping the confirm password feature.

Comment: Yes, I believe it was dropped because it seemed unnecessary.